# Why is this UV Map face not displaying correctly?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, image

Edit 1
Here's the blender file:
[image]

Also here's a better image of the face in question

!https://imgur.com/a/PKXzx

The texture of my model is not displaying correctly onto my mesh.

It revolves around the UV/Image Editor, I'm trying to get that face in the two panels of the first image on the right to show the texture as it does in the image on the left. (note that the image on the left is the right arm of the character and the other two are of left arm)

[image]

[image]

The dotted face in particular. Not sure if this helps but when I scale that face in the uv map, I've noticed the texture is flipped.

Comment: Please give more detail of what your problem is, or what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The problem I'm having is better shown in this image (https://imgur.com/a/yMSLp) and it revolves around the UV/Image Editor, I'm trying to get that face in the two images on the right to show the texture as it does in the image on the left. (note that the image on the left is the right arm of the character and the other two are of left arm) hope this helps.

Comment: Try moving the vertices around and see if the 'dotted' face goes away. In my experience, you don't want that 'dotted' face. It usually means that there are two faces overlapping.

Comment: In the uv/image editor i did find an overlapping face (which is the selected non-dotted one), however I think both are necessary as one is used for the right arm and the other for the left. But one thing I did notice is that edges of the white triangle outlined in red are connected to the point of the dotted triangle (note that this triangle [in yellow] doesn't have a face there), while the triangle overlapping the dotted one doesn't have this. (The yellow highlight shows where both the selected triangles were before I moved them) (https://imgur.com/a/RWg3B)

Comment: If you have more useful information, use the 'edit' link at the bottom of your post to add it in.  Go to the opposite arm, and look at how the UV map is shaped, and duplicate that shape on the other side. You said the other side was working, correct? Also, [upload your blend file here so others can look at the issue closer](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: The face must be flipped in the UV editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's becouse your triangle is rotated. Let's i describe it in image:

[image]

your vertex number 1 is on position of vertex 3, n.2 on position of 1, n.3 on pos. 2.

so it look like all vertex on right place, but this places are wrong:

[image]

Selecting in mesh uv sync mode displays that one vertex is on different positions in UV.